# alaert dialog box disappeared immediately

Tags: java, android

I created an AlertDialog box with an ok button when email and password are null. But the AlertDialog box does immediately disappear. I want it to disappear after clicking on the ok button and stay at this loginactivity.java. How can I do that? Please help me.

**Here is piece of my code  Loginactivity.java**

```
mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            my_username = mEmailView.getText().toString();
            my_password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();
           // Log.v("Username", "Username is " + my_username);

            savePreferences("Login onClick storedName", mEmailView.getText().toString());
            savePreferences("Login onClick storedPass", mPasswordView.getText().toString());

            if (my_username.isEmpty() || my_password.isEmpty() ) {

                Log.v("Login button onClick", "Login onClick 2 input are empty ");


                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                // current activity
                                LoginActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, just close
                                // the dialog box and do nothing
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }else{

                Log.v("Login button onClick", "Login onClick 2 input are not empty ");

                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                Intent intent= new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                b.putString("Username", my_username);
                b.putString("Password", my_password);
                b.putString("flag", "add");
                intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(intent);

                // Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                // startActivity(i);
            }
```

Comment: after showing the dialog, you are launching an activity. If you want to launch that activity on some button click, move the launching code.

Answer (score 1):

After Showing Dialog you are launching activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

remove this lines and run.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you first use the builder to build the dialog, and then you show it. That's right. But then, why start the activity *again*? There is no need to do that! This is also the reason for the disappearing alert dialog. When a new activity is started, alert dialogs are dismissed automatically!

So you just need to delete these line:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

*Showing a dialog doesn't leave the current activity*.

Answer (score 0):

```
 LoginActivity.this.finish() you have to replace this line with "dialog.dismiss()"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are launching code after dialog show therefore alert dialog disappear put startActivityCode in ok or cancel button of alert dialog like below code:

```
mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            my_username = mEmailView.getText().toString();
            my_password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();
           // Log.v("Username", "Username is " + my_username);

            savePreferences("Login onClick storedName", mEmailView.getText().toString());
            savePreferences("Login onClick storedPass", mPasswordView.getText().toString());

            if (my_username.isEmpty() || my_password.isEmpty() ) {

                Log.v("Login button onClick", "Login onClick 2 input are empty ");


                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                // current activity
                                LoginActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, just close
                                // the dialog box and do nothing

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();


            }else{

                Log.v("Login button onClick", "Login onClick 2 input are not empty ");

                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                Intent intent= new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                b.putString("Username", my_username);
                b.putString("Password", my_password);
                b.putString("flag", "add");
                intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(intent);

                // Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                // startActivity(i);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of this code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
```